# Access UI Elements from C function

Tags: iphone

In an iPhone application, I have some plain C functions. Is it possible to access UI elements (declared on viewcontroller) in these functions?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to access a variable declared one view in another view?

Comment: Well, in fact I have C functions not declared inside .h file, but directly implemented in .m file. I can call them inside view's methods, however inside those C functions I can't access UI elements

Comment: Yes, is possible. Is't it easier to write the function in OBjective-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul, hopefully you will find this thread helpful:
[Unable to call an Objective C method from a C function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304885/unable-to-call-an-objective-c-method-from-a-c-function)